# Use jQuery to add form fields and PHP Sessions to remember the fields were added

Tags: php, jquery, session

I am creating a multi-paged form and now i am consulting the Stack guru's for some assistance;

On this page the user can add more input fields [type=text] onto the page

So basically there is a singular input for "CHILD NAME" then a Add button to allow the user to add more children if they have more than one.

My form allows you to go backwards and forwards, the form remembers what was input, how would i get jQuery and php to remember that the form fields were added so they are not hidden when the user re-vists the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well with adding inputs you can do:

```
$('form').append('<input>',{type: 'text', name: 'input_name'})
```

and you can save previous parts of the form data with php $_SESSIONs

example of a form:

in php you will get all the post (or get) values:

```
$_POST = array ('name1' => 'me', 'name2' => 'you' )...
```

and then you can save those in a session with:

```
$_SESSION['lastpostedvalues'] = $_POST;
```

or something like that.

remember to have `session_start()` at the top of the php file

Comment: i see, could you give an example of an input generated from jquery and how it would be stored in Session ?

Comment: edited to add how you could put the post values into a session.

Comment: the jquery code does not include the form name or the type variables

Comment: i have no idea what your form name is lol. put in your own name :-)

Comment: sorry i mean the values "name" and "type" from the code lol i wasn't refering to my form & my form is called form :D

Comment: can you please explain. im still not sure what you are getting at :-\

Comment: Mani, with the code you added yesterday i seem to be getting a foreach loop problem when i load another instance on the same page.

Comment: No offense, but I have no idea why this answer was marked as right. The user was asking how to display previously hidden (or non-created dynamic fields) then repopulate them with data stored in session before. This answer only tells somebody how to ultimately add a new input field with jquery and how to store existing data in a PHP session.

Comment: @JM4 that is what all of the answers here answer. How to create the inputs, and store them into a session on form post.

Comment: @Neal - given the form was created dynamically (only 1 field shows at page load) the user was asking how to show all 1+N fields the user created and filled out information on. Looking at other questions the user marked correct, it seems he just gets tired of waiting and marks anything posted. I am not discounting your answer because it is partially correct but for those who come to this page looking for guidance later, it is not answered the way it was asked.

Answer (score 0):

try this if it helps

html code

```
<span>

    <span id="childs"></span>

    <input type="text" id="testid" />

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add" />
</span>
```

jQuery ---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $('#childs').append('<a href="">'+$('#testid').val()+'</a><br />');
    $value=$('#testid').val();
    $.get('somePHPCodewhichaddsToSession.php',{
        data:$values
    },function(data){
        //some staff after the session is add
    });

});
});
/*PHP code to add the sessions*/


if(isset($_GET['data'])){
    $_SESSION['AnyName']=$_GET['data']; //this could be an array to hold all the childern names
     if(isset($_SESSION['AnyName']))
         echo true; //handle this return in your ajax call oncomplete callback
    else
        echo false;
}

/* PHP code to dispaly the childrens*/

//get the array from the session

if(isset($_SESSION['AnyName']){
     get the values and display or do something with them
       $values= $_SESSION['AnyName']
   }
```

** Make sure to format the html to fit your needs

http://jsfiddle.net/tsegay/5VhVp/